# How to make printk in my module show messages on serial consoles regardless of the value of boot parameter console=

Tags: linux-kernel, message, kernel-module, printk

The board I'm working has one serial console (ttyS0) and I would like to make my kernel module show any errors to this serial console. I understand that one possibility would be using `console=ttyS0` parameter to print messages appear on the serial, however, for my case specifically *I cannot set this parameter* (e.g. my bootloader doesn't allow setting `console=...`) and my module messages end up being lost. Also, I understand that these kernel messages could be retrieved in dmesg/syslog but that's not what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to make my module write to a serial console(s) (e.g. ttyS0) regardless of what is defined for the `console=...` kernel parameter?

Comment: I think you misunderstood something about your boot loader (which one, btw?). The parameter is purely for kernel's and it's placed in the kernel command line. But if you wish to have an answer to your question, then *__No__, there is no way to achieve this* in your case. Kernel must know ahead the device it will use as kernel console.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying 0andriy.